# How to use regexFilter at JTable properly

Tags: java, regex, swing, jtable, rowsorter

i have a JTable and want to filter it. Therefore i have a textfield, where i get my input from:

```
    eingabeF.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            String eingabe = eingabeF.getText();
            System.out.println(eingabe);
            MovieUI.getTable().getSorter().setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(".*"+ eingabe +".*"));
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

but it doesn't work. How to use regexFilter in the right way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- use `DocumentListener` (for all `JTextComponen`ts) instead of `KeyListener`
- read [Oracle tutorial How to use Tables - Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for working code example about `JTextField`, `DocumentListener` and with `RowFilter.regexFilter()`

Comment: Its a part of an exercise, where i have to use KeyListener...but also if i use DocumentListener and do it like in the tutorial, it doesn't work. Always, when i type anything in the textfield, all rows disappear

Comment: i have to use KeyListener, its crazy, never mind, then you have to move code to keyPressed, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: i know, that its crazy...hate it. When i move it to keyPressed, i have to type the next key, that i get the first one. By typing "fight" it gets "figh". And still all rows disappear, by typing anything in the textfield.

Comment: Okay, it works now. But any advice, that it doesn't matter if i type large or lower cases?

Comment: I did this: RowFilter.regexFilter(("?i") + Pattern.quote(".*" + eingabe + ".*"), 1) But i alway get this error: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 0
?i.*\Qe\E.*
^

Comment: again for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for JTable/XxxTableModel in local variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,  This is working fine in my project
You can use this search method for every JTable in your class,

```
  private void txtSearchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         

        search(myTable,myTextField);

    }

  public void search(JTable table, JTextField txtSearch) {

        // I have used txtSearch1 in the RowColorRenderer class
        this.txtSearch1 = txtSearch;
         //Create new table sorter for the table
        TableRowSorter sorter = new TableRowSorter(table.getModel());
        //Add row filter to the tablerowsorter (regex)
        sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i).*\\Q" + txtSearch.getText() + "\\E.*"));
        //Apply the results to the output table
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        if (table.getRowCount() == 0) {
            //Display message like nothing found
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            RowColorRenderer rowRenderer = new RowColorRenderer(i);
            TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            column.setCellRenderer((TableCellRenderer) rowRenderer);
        }
    }
```

and this is cell renderer to change the color of cell in which the Text from search JTextField is found

```
   public class RowColorRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private int colNo = 0;

        RowColorRenderer(int col) {
            colNo = col;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
                    isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            JComponent jc = (JComponent) comp;
            if (!isSelected) {
                if (table.getValueAt(row, colNo) != null) {
                    String str = table.getValueAt(row, colNo).toString();

                    if (!str.isEmpty()) {
                        if (Pattern.compile("(?i).*\\Q" + txtSearch1.getText() + "\\E.*").matcher(str).find()) {
                            if (!txtSearch1.getText().equals("")) {
                                //   setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                                //  setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
                                //  setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
                                setForeground(Color.blue);
                            } else {
                                setBackground(table.getBackground());
                                setForeground(table.getForeground());
                                // setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
                            }
                        } else {
                            setBackground(table.getBackground());
                            setForeground(table.getForeground());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
```